# How can I list contributors in a Git repo with dates active?

Tags: git

I'd like to get a list of all contributors to some Git repository. For each contributor I'd also like to print out their earliest and latest commit timestamp. Is there a way to extract this information using git's command line?

Comment: This could help part of the puzzle... https://gehrcke.de/2015/06/git-list-authors-sorted-by-the-time-of-their-first-contribution/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the list you asked for, with author email and author date.

```
git log --pretty=format:"%ae %ai" | sort | awk 'contributor == $1 { lastContribution = $0 } contributor != $1 { contributor = $1; if (lastContribution) print lastContribution; print } END { print lastContribution }'
```

If you want committer email or commit date instead, replace `%a` with `%c`.
If you want name instead of email, replace `%ae` by `%an`.

Answer (score 2):

To show all users and the number of commits you can use:

```
git shortlog -sn
```

and you can use the output to get informations about each author via:

```
git log --author=<pattern>
```